# select option default to a value with condition

Tags: angular

I have a select box. I'm displaying methods which are available using ngFor. But if I have only one method then I need to default the methods select box to that value. Not sure how to do that.

```html
              <select id='methods' class="icon" (change)="methodChange($event.target.value)" formControlName="method">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option *ngFor="let method of methods" [value]="method.name">{{method.name}} </option>
                <optgroup label="----"></optgroup>
                <option value="addmethod">method</option>
                <option value="editmethod">edit method</option>
              </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bind the select value to a component property using [(ngModel)] and use the ngOnInit function to set that property when the component loads.

Here is your view:

```
<select id='methods' class="icon" (change)="methodChange($event.target.value)" formControlName="method" [(ngModel)]="defaultval">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let method of methods" [value]="method.name">{{method.name}} </option>
    <optgroup label="----"></optgroup>
    <option value="addmethod">method</option>
    <option value="editmethod">edit method</option>
</select>
```

And then in your controller:

```
defaultval = null;

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.methods.length == 1) {
        this.defaultval = this.methods[0].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I write defaultVal = null inside the onInit?

Comment: this.defaultVal = null;